# MVC5 Multiselect checkbox values not being passed to database

Tags: jquery, razor, checkbox, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm implementing multiselect checkboxes using the following code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="Location" value="S" /> S &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="Location" value="I" /> I &nbsp;
<input type="checkbox" name="Location" value="T" /> T 
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Location)
```

I have some jQuery to pull the values:

```
$("#Location").change(function () {
  // grab the selected options
  var grid = $.map($("input[name='Location']:checked"), function (e, i) {
      return e.value;
  });
  $("#Location").val(grid);
  console.log("Location: " + $("#Location").val());
});
```

The console outputs what I would expect, for example:

```
Location: S,I,T
```

if all checkboxes are checked. For some reason though when the data is saved into the database only the first letter is being saved. The database field is nvarchar(6) so it's not that it's being truncated at that end. Any ideas why the full value of the string is not being passed?

Comment: Change the name of the checkboxes. You posting back 4 values all with the same name. Since your property is `string` and not `string[]`, only the first checked checkbox value is bound (the subsequent ones are ignored)

Comment: But why not just make the property `string[] Location`, then get rid of all the javascript and the hidden input, and in the controller, you can use `string.Join()` to save the value.

Comment: But isn't the value being bound the one generated by the jQuery which brings together all the values?

Comment: No. Say the 2nd and 3rd checkboxes are checked. The submit would post back `location=I&location=T&location=I,T`. The `DefaultModelBinder` reads the first one (`I`) and sets `model.Location="I";`, but because the property is not `IEnumerable`, the subsequent values are ignored.

Comment: So if I change the class from string to string[], what do I need to do once it's posted to join the array into a single string for storing in the database?

Comment: use [string.Join()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). but seriously, why would you store relational data in database that way.

Comment: Will have to ask for Location in four places on form, there can be between one and six different responses for each one. Solution needed quickly and didn't see a better way to go in this case, they expect to analyse the values in a comma delimited list. Just tried using the join but obviously not doing it right, would appreciate an example

Comment: If you remove the hidden input and the scripts and make the property `string[] Location { get; set; }`, then when you post, the value of model.Location will be `["S", "I", "T"]` assuming all checkboxes are checked. Then `string joinedValues = string.Join("," model.Location)`

Comment: Tried but getting an error that "The type 'string[]' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.StructuralTypeConfiguration<TStructuralType>.Property<T>(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TStructuralType,T>>)'

Comment: What method? That has nothing to do with your question. And I thought you wanted to save the comma separated string (i.e. the value of `joinedValues` in my last comment)

Comment: I use EF6, the mapping threw that error and the controller threw an error about converting between string and string[] so it doesn't look as if this solution will work for me, thanks for your time anyway.

Comment: You need to use a view model when you edit data, not the data model.

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is because server receives a few values with the name `Location` but accept only the first one received.

To solve your problem you have to give different names to your checkboxes in the form, and then process them respectively on the server.

Comment: Can you advise on the best way to process in the controller?